# Pandas map values from Dictionary efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe `df` :-

| ID | COST | 1F | 2F | 3F | 4G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 362 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 269 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 346 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 342 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have a `total_cost` dictionary :

total_cost ={'1F' : 0.047,'2F' : 0.03,'3F': 0.023,'4G': 0.025}

I want to add a `TOTAL_COST` column such that wherever `1` is present, `COST`*(value from total_cost dictionary) for that col is to be multiplied and added together.

The dataframe has around a  milion records, what would be the most efficient way to do this?
Expected `df` :-

| ID | COST | 1F | 2F | 3F | 4G | TOTAL_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 362 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 28.236 |
| 2 | 269 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 8.07 |
| 3 | 346 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 43.25 |
| 4 | 342 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slicing to only get the columns present as keys in your dictionary, then multiply by it, aggregate as [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) per row and [`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by the COST:

```
df['TOTAL_COST'] = df[list(total_cost)].mul(total_cost).sum(axis=1).mul(df['COST'])
```

Or, cast the dictionary as Series (the non matching columns will become NaN):

```
df['TOTAL_COST'] = df.mul(pd.Series(total_cost)).sum(axis=1).mul(df['COST'])
```

Output:

```
   ID  COST  1F  2F  3F  4G  TOTAL_COST
0   1   362   0   1   1   1      28.236
1   2   269   0   1   0   0       8.070
2   3   346   1   1   1   1      43.250
3   4   342   0   0   0   0       0.000
```

Comment: It worked with less execution time. very helpful one line solution